# Possible $\mathsf{NP}$ complete problem from number theory

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity, computer-science, factorization

A candidate $\mathsf{NP}$ complete variant of factoring was posted in https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring, where  decision problem $\text{BOUNDED-FACTORING} = \{\langle L, U, N \rangle \;|\; (\exists n\in \{L, \ldots, U\})[n | N]\}$ was shown to be $\mathsf{NP}$ hard under randomized reductions under some results (http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/83/3/532) on prime numbers. A number theory question was posted in [Are there effective small intervals in which primes are dense?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212816/are-there-effective-small-intervals-in-which-primes-are-dense) whose answer provides a slightly different reduction from a bound of different nature on prime numbers.

Is there a different technique to remove randomness without any unknown conjectures and make the reduction deterministic?

Comment: That post of mine and the answer to it together are enough to make the reduction effective (in the mathematical sense). $\;$

Comment: Are you using "effectively" in the informal sense? $\:$ If yes, then [Cramér's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér%27s_conjecture) is makes [version #4 of Shor's answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/revisions/4785/4) "effectively deterministic". $\:$ If no, what does "effectively deterministic" mean? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer what does effective mean here concretely?

Comment: In this case, it means the proof allows construction of a _specific_ algorithm and polynomial runtime-bound, rather than just showing that such _exist_. ​ ​