# consecutive prime gaps and explicit bound

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I am aware of the theorem that $p_{n+1}- p_n \leq n^{0.525}$ which is true for all sufficiently large numbers due to Baker, but if i want to make the implicit "for all sufficiently large numbers" explicit, is it known that $p_{n+1}-p_n \leq c n^{\alpha}$ for all $n \geq 1$ and for small $c$, lets say $c \leq 2$ and $\alpha \leq 0.55$ ?

Any ref that can give me the explicit numbers or a way to construct them would be great.

Thank you, also i posted the question yesterday on MSE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The result you quote is due to Baker-Harman-Pintz (2000). I am not aware of any concrete effective version of this result, but if you increase the exponent $0.525$ to $2/3$, then such a variant is available by the [work of Dudek](https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4233). See also my response to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212816/are-there-effective-small-intervals-in-which-primes-are-dense).

Comment: Thx, so is there $\alpha <1$ such that $c\leq 2$ and $n_0$ or $x_0$ is small say less than $10^{10}$ or $10^{12}
$ ?

Comment: @Ahmad: Dudek's result implies that if $n$ is very-very large (doubly exponentially large), then $p_{n+1}-p_n<n^{3/4}$. It is not clear to me what can be said for smaller $n$'s unconditionally.