# Conjecture: $ x\leqslant f(x)\leqslant x+x^{\log_{113}13} \{x|1\leqslant x\leqslant+\infty,x\in \mathrm{positive~integer}\}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Function f(x) is the most closest prime number not less than $x$.

$f(5)=5\qquad  f(9)=11$

Conjecture: $ x\leqslant f(x)\leqslant x+x^{\log_{113}13}   \{x|1\leqslant x\leqslant+\infty,x\in \mathrm{positive~integer}\}$?

States that there is a prime number between $x$ and $x+x^{\log_{113}13}$ for every positive integer $x$?

For all positive integer $n$, where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number.

$p_{n+1}-1-p_n\leqslant {\left(p_n\right)}^{\log_{113}13} \qquad$ ?

Comment: I assume you'll be editing the post to fix the poor formatting...?

Comment: You could add the context that the upper bound in the conjecture is attained for $x=114$.

Comment: [Since there is a prime between $x$ and $x+x^{(21/40)}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture), your conjecture holds for large $x$.

Comment: There is not a prime between 114 and 114+114^(21/40)

Comment: 114 is not a large $x$, scibee.

Comment: @GerryMyerson :  Not that it actually matters, but I read your comment as saying that there is a prime between $x$ and $x^{21/40}$ for **all** $x$ and that this implies the conjecture for **large** $x$.  So scibee's response is in fact on target and (at least given my reading, which I think is the natural one), "114 is not a large $x$" is not relevant.  (Of course my reading is not the same as what you actually meant.)

Comment: It would be very good to include an explanation of why you expect this might be true.

Comment: @Steven, the link in Bullet's comment actually says there is a prime between $x$ and $x+x^{21/40}$ for all large $x$, so the first half of Bullet's comment is misleading, and scibee is correct to object. But the second part of Bullet's comment is correct, and is what I had in mind when I posted my comment.

Comment: @GerryMyerson :  Agreed all around --- and my apologies for mistakenly referring to Bullet's comment as "your" comment.

Comment: I truly apprecuate your helps

Answer (score 4):

This result is true for all sufficiently large $x$ due to a theorem of R.C. Baker, G. Harman, and J. Pintz (see: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/BakerHarmanPintz.pdf, or the official page in the journal: https://academic.oup.com/plms/article-abstract/83/3/532/1479119). In particular, they proved the following statement:

There exists a positive real number $x_0$ such that for all $x > x_0$, the interval $[x, x+ x^{0.525}]$ contains a prime number.

Answer (score 3):

Let us assume the Riemann Hypothesis. Carneiro, Milinovich, and Soundararajan [proved in 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04122) that for any $x>4$, there exists a prime in $[x,x+\frac{22}{25}\sqrt{x}\log x]$. Using this result, it is straightforward to prove the OP's conjecture for $x\geq 10^{47}$ (under the Riemann Hypothesis).

See also my response to this [related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312236/consecutive-prime-gaps-and-explicit-bound/).

Comment: See also Theorem 5 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04122

Comment: @MicahMilinovich: Thank you very much! I updated my response along with the numerics (as I was off by a factor of 2 for the gap).