# Bertrand postulate- stronger version

Tags: nt.number-theory

Can we prove: let $2<p<q$ be two consequtive prime numbers, then there is always a prime number in interval $(q,p+q]$ (ie. betwen $q$ and $p+q$). In other words: if $p_{n-1}<p_n< p_{n+1}$ are any three consequtive primes, then $p_{n+1}<p_{n}+p_{n-1}$. Bertrand postulate is a consequence of this statement, since $p+q<2q$

Comment: For large enough $p$, there will be at least two primes between $p$ and $2p$. The second of these primes will satisfy $r<2p<p+q$. Result of Nagura mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate#Better_results) will give you how large $p$ has to be, and then we just need to check some small $p$.

Comment: Where can i find the proof for at least two primes betwen p and 2p for large enough p?

Comment: As I mentioned, it follows from Nagura's result. Wikipedia has a reference.

Comment: In fact the ratio of consecutive primes tends to 1 by the prime number theorem. Another consequence of the prime number theorem is that, asymptotically, there are about as many primes between $x$ and $2x$ as primes up to $x$. So Bertrand's postulate can be strengthened significantly. In this direction, the best result is due to Baker-Harman-Pintz (2000): for $x$ sufficiently large, there is always a prime in the interval $[x,x+x^{21/40}]$.

Comment: 1. Concerning effective Nagura: see the Wikipedia page suggested by Wojowu. 2. Concerning effective Baker-Harman-Pintz: see my response at https://mathoverflow.net/q/312236/

Comment: In my question i was hopping on some sort of "algebraic" proof ( like Erdos proof of Bertrand postulate ) without use of analytic methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Section 4 of P. Dusart [[Math. Comp. 68(1999), 411--415](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1999-68-225/S0025-5718-99-01037-6/S0025-5718-99-01037-6.pdf)], for any $x\ge3275$ there is a prime $p$ such that
$$x\le p\le x\left(1+\frac1{2\log^2x}\right)\le x\left(1+\frac1{2\log^2 3275}\right)<1.01x.$$

For any integer $n\ge463$, we have $p_n>3275$ and hence
$$p_{n+1}<1.01p_n<p_n+\frac12p_n<p_n+p_{n-1}.$$